# Is the introduction chapter 0 or 1?

Tags: metapost

I know this question, is not directly about tex:

What is the norm in science: Is the introduction the 1st or 0st chapter?

Comment: It really depends - sometimes yes, sometimes no: perhaps the `introduction` will not have a number, and the first numbered chapter will come after it. Is the `metapost` tag appropriate?

Comment: @cmhughes It's not a TeX post, it's a metapost...

Comment: @AlanMunn I hope you are aware that MetaPost is a language for creating graphics (which is being discussed here on tex.SE), so that tag is not appropriate=)

Comment: @flawr I hope you are aware that it's a pun on *post*, not a literal statement.